# Obtener varios datos de una columna en una tabla para una fila de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tengo dos tablas: trabajador y evaluacion,
**la tabla trabajador** con campos: id, nombre, cedula;

**la tabla evaluacion** con campos: id, id_trabajador, evaluador1, evaluador2, evaluador3;[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
los campos evaluador1, evaluador2, evaluador3 son tipo int, numeros de identidad(correspondiente a la cedula en tabla trabajador), pero deseo obtener es por nombre haciendo inner join con tabla trabajador, y como son 3 campos (evaluador1, evaluador2, evaluador3) que dependen de uno(trabajador.cedula), no sé como hacerlo, solo logro obtener el nombre de primer evaluador(trabajador) así:

```
select trabajador.nombre as evaluador1, evaluacion.evaluador2, evaluacion.evaluador3 from trabajador INNER JOIN evaluacion ON evaluacion.evaluador1 = trabajador.cedula
```

Quiero que me devuelva los nombres de los 3 evaluadores, que a la final son 3 trabajadores, extrayendo el nombre de la otra tabla, no que me devuelva el numero, sino el nombre

Comment: no entiendo tu problema.. si por cada trabajar tenes 3 evaluadores, cual es el problema? podrias agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: quiero que la consulta devuelva el nombre de los 3 evaluadores: Juan, Pepe, Maria, y que no devuelva 12341234, 46456, 436456. se devolver un solo campo el nombre por inner join, pero los 3 no

Comment: por favor, usa el boton [edit] y aclara bien entonces tu pregunta... porque no sabemos que datos hay en cada campo.. los nombres de los campos no nos dicen nada...

Comment: Listo ya lo edité

Comment: Entonces, supongo, que en evaluador hay numeros de cedula?

Comment: Sí hay numeros de cedulas en evaluador1, evaluador2, evaluador3, quiero que me retorne no esos numeros, sino el nombre de los 3 por cada registro, para eso está la otra tabla trabajador, para sacar el nombre de acuerdo a la cedula, sé sacarlo pero de un solo campo por cada registro, no de los tres evaluador1, evaluador2, evaluador3

Comment: ok... es simple..ahora la respondo.. pero fijate toda la informacion que le faltaba a la pregunta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener los valores que vos queres, podemos usar subquerys en cada columna para traer lo que necesitamos...

```
select 
    (select nombre from trabajadores t1 where t1.id_trabajador = e.id_trabajador) as id_trabajador,
    (select nombre from trabajadores t1 where t1.evaluador1= e.evaluador1) as evaluador1,
    (select nombre from trabajadores t1 where t1.evaluador2= e.evaluador2) as evaluador2,
    (select nombre from trabajadores t1 where t1.evaluador3= e.evaluador3) as evaluador3
from evaluacion e 
where e.id_trabajador = 1
```

aca, en cada columna, vamos y buscamos el nombre que corresponde de la tabla trabajadores, basados en la columna que estamos